# Where do I post a question on report design?

Tags: discussion

I currently do work in creating reports using a business intelligence system. For years I've known it's common to include the name of the user who ran the report in the report, possibly the footer. Senior management suggests we don't do that in our new reporting system. I feel that it has ties to data tracking / auditing, but I'm looking for suggestions on where I can get specific references to such a practice.

I felt this might start in InfoSec META because it deals with data security, though not the technical aspects of such.

So where can I post this question as to "Why do we include the user name in reports?"

edit: Specifically then, I suppose I would want to ask "Why do we care to see who ran the report printed on the report in situations where IT can (eventually) find the information from logs?"

It is for example, listed as a "Best Practice" on Microsoft's Reporting and Monitoring Best Practices article for MMC ([Reporting: Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb226815(v=vs.85).aspx)), though it applies more widely to Information Design.

Comment: This isn't to do with data security or privacy, despite the fact it will have implications. Realistically I'd say this is down to individual company policy. Workplace.SE would say something similar. The simple answer to your question is "so you know who ran the report"

Comment: The site isn't even in beta yet, but the Area 51 proposal for [Technical Communication](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101439/technical-communication) Seems like a possibility in the future. I even think this might make a good proposed sample question there.

Comment: Picking up on @RoryAlsop's point, you *could* ask here specifically about the implications on security / privacy.

Comment: Excellent comments. Though since IT could look at logs to see who ran the report if it was found in the 'wild' and did not include the username, I don't really need to ask about implications. I already know them ;). I would suggest that Rory's Comment is an answer if that helps.